# Android -- Unable to resolve activity in JUnit test only for some activities

Tags: android, junit, android-activity

When I run a JUnit test for one of my activities I get the above error, but not for another activity. Both activities are in the same package.

Here's my barebones code for activity that doesn't work. (the one that does work is the same, just switch the activity name).

```
public class CounterTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Reward>{

Activity mActivity;


public CounterTest() {
    super("com.morningsun.caffeinecounter", Reward.class);

}

@Override
protected void setUp(){
    try{
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = this.getActivity();


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}

public void test(){

    Assert.assertTrue(1==1);

}
```

And here's my manifest instrumentation info

`

```
    <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.missaion.caffeinecounter.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <instrumentation 
        android:targetPackage="com.morningsun.caffeinecounter" 
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
</manifest>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        package="com.morningsun.caffeinecounter"
        android:versionCode="2"
         android:versionName="1.05">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/Title">

        <activity android:name=".CaffeineCounterActivity"
                  android:label="@string/Title"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity 
            android:name=".DrinkSelector"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:label="@string/Select"  />  

        <activity 
            android:name=".Plot"    
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:label="@string/PlotData"  />  

        <activity 
            android:name=".Info"    
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:label="@string/InfoText"  />  

          <activity 
            android:name=".SendDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:label="@string/SaveFile"  />    


        <activity 
            android:name=".DrinkDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/AddDrink"  />

        <activity 
            android:name=".DrinkDialogNonLinear"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/AddDrink"  />

        <activity 
            android:name=".EditType"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/EditType"  />

        <activity 
            android:name=".EditTypeStarbucks"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:label="@string/Select"  />  

        <activity 
            android:name=".DrinkUpdater"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/EditDrink"  />



        <activity 
            android:name=".AmountDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true" />

          <activity 
            android:name=".NewTypeDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:label="@string/AddType" />



        <activity 
            android:name=".DayList"
            android:label="@string/DateList"/>

         <activity 
            android:name=".TypeList"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:label="@string/Types"/>


         <activity 
            android:name=".DayDrinkList"
            android:label="@string/DateDrinkList">

        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".SodaList"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/SelectDrink"  />

         <activity 
            android:name=".LimitDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true" />



    </application>
</manifest>
```

The other posts on this topic say to check the instrumentation targetPackage and to check the values in the constructor super, which seem okay to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the error messages:

```
03-30 13:35:08.853: W/System.err(1727): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.morningsun.caffeinecounter/.Reward }
03-30 13:35:08.853: W/System.err(1727):     at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:371)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivityWithIntent(InstrumentationTestCase.java:119)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity(InstrumentationTestCase.java:97)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:98)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at com.missaion.caffeinecounter.test.CounterTest.setUp(CounterTest.java:33)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
03-30 13:35:08.863: W/System.err(1727):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

Comment: Please post the manifest file for the Activities being tested.

Comment: The `Reward` class which you are testing is not listed in the manifest that you posted. Double-check that you have an `<activity>` tag for this class.

Comment: Added as an answer. Feel free to accept/upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Reward class which you are testing is not listed in the manifest that you posted. Double-check that you have an `<activity>` tag for this class.

Comment: Is I am using the BaseActivity then I won't list it in AndroidManifest, then how can I resolve this error?

Comment: @AanalMehta I don't know what `BaseActivity` is. I'm pretty sure you still have to list all activities in AndroidManifest. If you still need help, you should post your own question by clicking the Ask Question button at the top right of any page on this site. Feel free to include a link to this page in your question.

Comment: The BaseActivity is like root activity. All other activities are extending this activity.

Comment: @AanalMehta If you need help, post a new question.